# Apache Flink vs Apache storm benchmark

Tags: apache-flink, benchmarking, apache-storm, flink-streaming

Is there any real benchmarks between Apache Flink and apache storm in real time processing based on performance comparison ?

Also if I want to make this performance comparison and implement it by myself, is there any stream API (like twitter API) that offers high throughput than twitter and which is open source ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some benchmarks for Stream Processing in general - but they are not always broadly applicable or accessible than the ones you can find for RDBMS.

A main question that you should answer for yourself at first is: **What exactly do you mean with performance?** There are different metrics how to benchmark such a system.

However, I will try here to list some benchmarking works, that helped me:

- A recent benchmarking framework that is implemented for Storm & Flink is the [Yahoo Streaming Benchmark](https://github.com/yahoo/streaming-benchmarks). It has a fixed internal architecture using Kafka & Redis and a predefined query/topology. Anyways, it is a good starting point.
- [Karimov et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08496) have a nice paper regarding benchmarking of these systems. It is worth a read since it really helps to understand possible metrics. Unfortunately, I can not find any implementation or further information on their workload (data and queries) that they use - so it is more helpful for understanding, I would say.
- [van Dongen et al](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339731660_Evaluation_of_Stream_Processing_Frameworks) are doing a more in-depth analysis of several stream processing systems and offer their source code at github. Unfortunately, there is no implementation for Storm. But anyways, there are some interesting ideas & contributions on how to build such a framework.

As you see, Stream Processing has a high diversity in the way you can set-up and benchmark your systems...